# Find $E[X(t)^2]$ given the partial differential equation... where $B(t), t\geq 0$ is a Brownian motion.

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Find $E[X(t)^2]$ given, $dX(t) = (\frac{4(1+t)^2 - X(t)^2)}{8X(t)})dt + \frac{1}{2}X(t)dB(t)$, where $B(t), t\geq 0$ is a Brownian motion.

I think I must apply $It\hat{o}$'s formula to $X(t)^2$ but I am not sure how to go about this.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am not sure how to go about a problem like this.

Comment: What exactly stops you from applying Itô's formula? Tell us a bit more about your thoughts...

Comment: (... and by the way, it is not polite to delete a question after it has been answered.... doesn't make me enthusiastic to answer any of your further questions.)

Comment: @saz I didn't delete anything actually, thank you very much for the previous answer, I wish I could view what you wrote for it...

Comment: @saz would you mind just giving me a hint in applying Itô's formula in this case?

Comment: You have to apply [Ito's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#It%C3%B4_drift-diffusion_processes_(due_to:_Kunita-Watanabe)) in order to calculate (the stochastic differential) of $X_t^2$. Unless you tell me more about your thoughts, it's hard to give you any furthr hints... it's really just plugging everything inside Itô's formula.